# pymongo: trouble iterating over aggregation results

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have issues understanding aggregations and their results with pymongo. Im trying to send an aggregation pipeline and it seems that I get all the expected data, but I can't use them somehow.

This is my script

```
import pymongo, json
from bson.json_util import dumps

client = pymongo.MongoClient('URL')
results = client['analytics']['metrics'].aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'name': 'metricName'
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$data.location', 
            'Count': {
                '$sum': 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': 'metricName', 
            'data': {
                '$addToSet': {
                    'location': '$_id', 
                    'count': '$Count'
                }
            }
        }
    }
]) # Pipeline return Array with single object containing my data see below for example

print(dumps(results, indent=4, sort_keys=True)) # prints json with expected data in expected format
result = results[0] # we do this because we receive an array of ojbject and we want the first one, but this fails
print(result)

# iterate over first element of results
for location in result.data:
    print(location.location + location.count)
```

This is my output:

```
/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3 /Users/me/Desktop/untitled.py 
[
    {
        "_id": "metricName",
        "data": [
            {
                "count": 13,
                "location": "ggg"
            },
            {
                "count": 12,
                "location": "fff"
            },
            {
                "count": 2,
                "location": "eee"
            },
            {
                "count": 10,
                "location": "ddd"
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "location": "ccc"
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "location": "bbb"
            },
            {
                "count": 6,
                "location": "aaa"
            }
        ]
    }
]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/untitled.py", line 31, in <module>
    result = results[0]
TypeError: 'CommandCursor' object is not subscriptable
```

when I started I just wanted to get a simple list of the locations and their count. Cant be too hard...

Comment: The `aggregate` method returns a _cursor_ (not an array). See [PyMongo Aggregate Example](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/aggregation.html?highlight=aggregate).

Comment: yea i figured. but how *can* I iterate my data? 
pymongo does not really feel pythonic, at all.

Comment: You just iterate over the cursor returned by the aggregate method.

Comment: but that does not work as you can see

Comment: When you print from cursor, the cursor gets exhausted. So, remove/comment those print statements before you iterate.

Comment: thanks, that was the issue. Strange behavior...

Comment: If you want to avoid the "strange behavior" convert the pipeline results / cursor to an array or list - which can be iterated or used as needed.